# How to input data from Excel to Python dictionary?

Tags: python, excel, list, dictionary, openpyxl

My code:

```
import openpyxl
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('master.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0]
result = {}
for k, v in zip(worksheet['A'], worksheet['B']):
    result[k.internal_value] = v.internal_value
 print(result)
```

The output I get:

```
{'PPPPP': '22', 'bbbbb': '20', 'ccccc': '30', 'ddddd': '40', 'eeeee': '50'}
```

Excel file:

[image]

The output I want:

```
{'PPPPP': ['22','10'], 'bbbbb': ['20','30'], 'ccccc': ['30','30'], 'ddddd': '40', 'eeeee': '50'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('master.xlsx', 0, None, ['A', 'B'])
result = {}
for x, y in zip(df['A'], df['B']):
    if x in result:
        result[x] = [result.get(x)]
        result[x].append(str(y))
    else:
        result[x] = str(y)
```

```
print(result)
{'ppp': ['10', '22'], 'bbb': ['20', '30'], 'ccc': ['30', '30'], 'ddd': '40', 'eee': '50'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a defaultdict, with an empty list as the default, and append each new value:

```py
from collections import defauldict
import openpyxl
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('master.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0]
result = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(worksheet['A'], worksheet['B']):
    result[k.internal_value].append(v.internal_value)
 print(result)
```

Here EVERY result will be a list, even when you only have one value. e.g. you will get `'ddddd': ['40']` but you should be able to handle all key value pairs consistently.